# How do I map my servlet correctly?

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, configuration

I have these two controllers:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controllerPath")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/sayHello")
    public String sayHello(Model model){
        ...
    }

}
```

---

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/restControllerPath")
public class RestController {

    @RequestMapping (value = "importantObject", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public  VeryImportantlClass getInformation(){
        ...
    }
}
```

The first controller renders to jsp

The second returns JSON.

Thus I want to have different configurations for this controllers

I have written the following in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher-rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/controllerPath/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher-rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restControllerPath/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When I send an http request from the browser, I see 404

if I use so style(below) for only one servlet:

```
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher-rest</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>
```

- controller methods invokes and I see good result.

How can I rewrite it using the first style ?

Comment: What has changed in the previous question?

Comment: another formulation. I hope clearler

Comment: What is the reason to use both servlets?

Comment: different ***-servlet.xml**

Comment: and question about mapping, your advice - offtopic

Comment: I think you should not mess up servlet and request mapping paths.

Answer (score 0):

Both the `mvc-dispatcher` and the `mvc-dispatcher-rest` are loading the same servlet.

So, you dont need two entries. Just use a single entry and map the root context `/` to the servlet.

Comment: but  one use **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml** other **mvc-dispatcher-rest-servlet.xml**

Comment: You should be able to combine the xml files. Is that a problem?

Comment: I want to have 2 different xml files.

Comment: I think mistake in pattern

Comment: Yes, But this trying was crashed